# redux-auto: async actions are not firing

Tags: promise, redux, redux-middleware

Hi all I have starting using this lib [redux-auto](https://npmjs.com/package/redux-auto) and I want to talk to the my sever.

Here is my code - store/user/get.js

```
export default function (user, payload, stage, result) {

  switch(stage){
    case 'FULFILLED':
        return result;
      break;
    case 'REJECTED':
      console.error(user, payload, stage, result)
      break;
    case 'PENDING':
      console.log("should be loading")
    default :
      break;
  }
  return user;
}

export function action (payload){
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/users/'+payload.id).then( data => data.json() );
  return payload;
}
```

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/codemeasandwich/redux-auto#action-files).
I cant see what is worry :(

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: From my UI I can call
`actoins.user.get({id:"5163032a622c051263c7b8ce"})`
and I can see the server call in my network tab
but the 'FULFILLED' is never called?

Comment: Does it call REJECTED or PENDING?

Comment: No, just "default" and returns the user. 
stage is undefined

Comment: According to the same docs you linked, stage isn't an argument. But then if I go deeper into the gitHub sources, the example has it there. So if I'm not wrong there's an inconsistency in docs. Try removing it from arguments or try the alternative declaration way which is right below the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the promise from the `fetch`

Change your action function to

```
export function action (payload){
  return fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/users/'+payload.id).then( data => data.json() );
}
```

If you don't return a promise, redux-auto will treat it like a normal reducer.

Comment: Funny when you get answered by the creator.